# extracting files from tar

Tags: tar

```
tar -xvf company_raw_2012-03-16.tgz --directory=/root/test --strip-components=4
```

I am using the following tar option to remove the leading directories and it is working as expected.

```
--strip-components NUMBER
strip NUMBER of leading components from file names before extraction
```

It works only when I know that there are going to be 4 sub-directories. I have tar files and I do not know if there will be 2, 3 or 4 folders inside.
How do I strip the entire path and extract files in the given "directory" path.

Comment: Are you talking about a variable `--strip-components` number in a single tar archive?  If so, if you have files with the same name in different directories in your tar archive, which one will be kept when you extract them?

Comment: The file names will be unique. And there will be exactly 3 files 3 or 4 folders down the line

Comment: What will happen if I provide all options using separate tar command? So three commands like --strip-components=3 --strip-components=4 --strip-components=5 # is it OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: read the tar file first ( tar tf ) and count the / in the output, then extract; or extract first, then move back all files up and delete empty directories.

Here is one way to achieve the first approach:

```
tar tf archive.tgz | tail -n1 | perl -ne '@l=split(/\//);print "$#l\n"'
```

Other methods are left as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just extract the tar file as normal without adding the switch `--strip-components`. Then, you can use the following find command to move all extracted files to some destination directory:

```
$ find <your_extracted_dir> -type f -exec mv -t /path/to/dest/dir {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tar --transform 's#.*/\([^/]*\)$#\1#' -xvf <filename>
```

this will use the regex on the file name and strip all the path from the filename
so all files are extracted to the current dir.

Comment: tar: unrecognized option `--transform' ### tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1

Comment: @shantanuo tar 1.15.1 does not support the `--transform` command. it was released in 2004-12-21, recent versions of gnu tar do support the command

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the tarball before issuing the extract with `--strip-components` by using:

```
tar -tzf filename.tar.gz | less
```

Comment: I need to use tar command in shell script. less does not help